# Нужен ли на письме дефис в разговорном "чё-т"?

Tags: орфография, дефис, разговорная-речь

С написанием "чё-то" ясно, а вот ещё более короткий разговорный вариант "чё-т"? Дефис остаётся на месте? Чтобы не получилось "чёт" (в контексте "чётный").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю, на письме разговорная речь должна максимально соответствовать устоявшимся правилам. Поэтому усечённую частицу ***-то*** следует писать через дефис.

*― Чё-т кваса захотелось!* [Сергей Осипов. Страсти по Фоме. Книга третья. Книга Перемен (1998)]

*― Ба! Поесть че-т найдется?!* [В. А. Ярмолинец. Лев в Москве // «Волга», 2015]

Хотя встречается, конечно, и слитное написание:

*― Я чёт не понял, по-другому ― это как?* [Алексей Моторов. Преступление доктора Паровозова (2013)]

*Чет до фига сообщений слетело из-за чистки, или мне так показалось.* [Автогонки-3 (форум) (2005)]

Словечко в словарях не указано, поэтому ориентироваться можно на своё чувство языка и принципы.